# How do I find which version of gcc corressponds to which version of binutils?

Tags: gcc, version, binutils

Exactly as the question sounds.

If there isn't a generic way to answer this question for any given version pair, can someone at least answer the specific question of whether gcc 3.4.6 and ld 2.15.92.0.2 correspond to each other?

Thanks.

I'm looking at the questions :-

[Help with linker failer: .gnu.linkonce.t](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1239730/help-with-linker-failer-gnu-linkonce-t)

[Please explain this linking error: referenced in section .rodata](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5333871/please-explain-this-linking-error-referenced-in-section-rodata)

The error I'm getting is exactly the same as the askers of those questions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They're separate projects with separate release schedules, so there's no single answer to your question.  The interface between them are things like the ELF, .a library and .o object file formats, which are well specified, so outside of fancy new features there's really no reason for them to be developed in tandem.

Is there a specific question you're trying to answer?  Like "what binutils version should I use?" or "What gcc/binutils versions shipped with Fedora 15?"

Comment: Well yes the specific question I'm trying to answer is also up there. I have a feeling some linker warning I keep getting about .gnu.linkonce.t.<something>. being defined in discarded sections is caused by a mismatch between the versions of the two tools. So, would it be fine to use the two versions of the tools I mentioned above together? I have several versions of each installed and I need to figure out if I'm using the right versions of the tools together.

Comment: added some context for the question.

Comment: Do those answers (the Red Hat bugzilla especially) not help you?  This sounds like a known bug in binutils that you'll need to upgrade to fix, not something you address by "matching" it to a gcc version.